# Seaborn catplot (kind='count') change bar chart to pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, pie-chart

I have the following looking df for my paper on corona-tracking-apps (pd.melt was used on it):

```
    CTQ-tool    opinion
0   Information and awareness purposes  unacceptable
1   Information and awareness purposes  unacceptable
2   Information and awareness purposes  acceptable
3   Information and awareness purposes  acceptable
4   Information and awareness purposes  unacceptable
... ... ...
2827    Central/Local data storage  NaN
2828    Central/Local data storage  NaN
2829    Central/Local data storage  NaN
2830    Central/Local data storage  NaN
2831    Central/Local data storage  NaN
2832 rows × 2 columns
```

I am using Seaborn library to make the following catplot:

code:

```
g = sns.catplot("opinion", col="CTQ-tool", col_wrap=4, data=df_original_small, kind="count", height=6.5, aspect=.8)
```

[image]

However, instead of displaying these in bar charts I would like to present them as pie charts. The Seaborn.catplot does not allow for something kind='count-pie'. Does anyone know a work around?

EDIT after TiTo question:

this is basicly what I want to see happen to all 8 bar charts:

[image]

Comment: could you explain a bit more how the pie charts should look like? You could use matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html

Comment: @TiTo it should look like a basic piechart (blue and orange totalling to 100% of the chart). I want to use the catplot (or something similar) because I want to represent the 8 charts in the same figure!

Comment: I meant how the data should be represented. I actually don't really understand your data. Here is another suggestion: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up using matplotlib library to build it up from the bottem:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')

IAP = df_original_small['Information and awareness purposes'].value_counts().to_frame().T
QE = df_original_small['Quarantine Enforcement'].value_counts().to_frame().T
CTCR = df_original_small['Contact Tracing and Cross-Referencing'].value_counts().to_frame().T
VPID = df_original_small['Voluntary provision of infection data'].value_counts().to_frame().T
QMA = df_original_small['Quarantine Monitoring App'].value_counts().to_frame().T
QRCode = df_original_small['QR code provided registration tracking'].value_counts().to_frame().T

total = pd.concat([IAP, QE, CTCR, VPID, QMA, QRCode])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)

labels = 'acceptable', 'unacceptable'
colors = ['#008fd5', '#fc4f30']
explode = (0, 0.1)
explode2 = (0.2, 0)

plt.title('Pie chart per CTQ-tool')
plt.tight_layout()

ax[0,0].pie(total.iloc[[0]], startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode, shadow=True)
ax[0,0].set_title('Information and awareness purposes', fontweight='bold')
ax[0,1].pie(total.iloc[[1]],  startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode, shadow=True)
ax[0,1].set_title('Quarantine Enforcement', fontweight='bold')
ax[1,0].pie(total.iloc[[2]],  startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode2, shadow=True)
ax[1,0].set_title('Contact Tracing and Cross-Referencing', fontweight='bold')
ax[1,1].pie(total.iloc[[3]], startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode, shadow=True)
ax[1,1].set_title('Voluntary provision of infection data', fontweight='bold')
ax[2,0].pie(total.iloc[[4]], startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode2, shadow=True)
ax[2,0].set_title('Quarantine Monitoring App', fontweight='bold')
ax[2,1].pie(total.iloc[[5]], startangle=90, colors=colors, wedgeprops={'edgecolor': 'black'}, autopct='%1.f%%', explode=explode, shadow=True)
ax[2,1].set_title('QR code provided registration tracking', fontweight='bold')


fig.suptitle('Public Opinion on CTQ-measures', fontsize=20, y=1.07, fontweight='bold', x=0.37)
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(7)
fig.legend(loc='best', labels=labels, fontsize='medium')
fig.tight_layout()

fig.savefig('Opinions_ctq')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do the same. So you couldn't do it with seaborn?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this if you want something quick:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'CTQ-tool':np.random.choice(['a','b','c','d'],50),
                  'opinion':np.random.choice(['acceptable','unacceptable'],50)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax = ax.flatten()
tab = pd.crosstab(df['CTQ-tool'],df['opinion'])
for i,cat in enumerate(tab.index):
    tab.loc[cat].plot.pie(ax=ax[i],startangle=90)
    ax[i].set_ylabel('')
    ax[i].set_title(cat, fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The question is about creating pie charts with `python` so I think you can use another visualization library like [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/), besides being a visualization library, `Plotly` is an *interactive* visualization library, so all your charts will be interactive!

Take a quick look at the [pie chart documentation](https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/).

Now, for your question, I created a small dataset and created two pie charts to illustrate how the code would be.

- First, import the needed libraries:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from kaleido.scopes.plotly import PlotlyScope # this will be used to export the chart as static image
```

- A toy dataset:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "CTQ-tool": [
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Information and awareness purposes",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
            "Quarantine Enforcement",
        ],
        "opinion": [
            "unacceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "acceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "acceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "acceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "unacceptable",
            "unacceptable",
        ],
    }
)
```

- Save the unique different *tools*:

```py
tools = df["CTQ-tool"].unique()
```

- Created aggregated data:

the following code, will group by the tool type and the by the opinion type, then create a new column `counts` storing the counts of each opinion type, for each tool.

```py
df_agg = df.groupby(by=["CTQ-tool", "opinion"]).size().reset_index(name="counts")
```

the new data frame `df_agg` would be:

```
|      | CTQ-tool                           | opinion      | counts |
| ---: | :--------------------------------- | :----------- | -----: |
|    0 | Information and awareness purposes | acceptable   |      1 |
|    1 | Information and awareness purposes | unacceptable |      5 |
|    2 | Quarantine Enforcement             | acceptable   |      2 |
|    3 | Quarantine Enforcement             | unacceptable |      4 |
```

- visualize the data (the fun part):
  Since this toy data has only two different tools, I created a `sub-plot` with onr row and two columns, but you can extend that for as many rows/columns you want.

```py
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "domain"}, {"type": "domain"}]])
```

then add each chart separately (you can do it with a for loop):

```py
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type": "domain"}, {"type": "domain"}]])

# Information and awareness purposes tool
fig.add_trace(
    go.Pie(
        values=df_agg[df_agg["CTQ-tool"] == tools[0]]["counts"],
        labels=df_agg[df_agg["CTQ-tool"] == tools[0]]["opinion"],
        pull=[0.2, 0.0],
        title=tools[0],
    ),
    1,
    1,
)

# Quarantine Enforcement tool
fig.add_trace(
    go.Pie(
        values=df_agg[df_agg["CTQ-tool"] == tools[1]]["counts"],
        labels=df_agg[df_agg["CTQ-tool"] == tools[1]]["opinion"],
        pull=[0.2, 0.0],
        title=tools[1],
    ),
    1,
    2,
)
```

- update chart layout:

```py
fig.update_layout(title_text="Public Opinion on CTQ-measures")

fig.show()
```

- finally, export as static image:

now that you've prepared your data and visualized it, it's time to save it as an image. Plotly creators built a tool for this: [Kaleido](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido).

You can simply use it as the following:

```py
scope = PlotlyScope()
fig_name = "Public-Opinion-on-CTQ-measures"
with open(f"{fig_name}.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(scope.transform(fig, "png"))
```

and the figure would be:

[image]